# iPhone/Facebook/Google App Engine Integration

Tags: iphone, python, facebook, google-app-engine

I am designing an iPhone app which needs the user to login to his/her Facebook account.

The app uses GAE (Google App Engine) as the background server (Python), so the problem now is that I don't know how GAE, iPhone and Facebook authentication works.

My guess is user logs in to FB from iPhone and will get an `access_token`, and then the iphone app sends the `access_token` to GAE so that GAE can recognize the user.

Is that correct? Or is there any tutorial about how to cooperate between these platforms?

I have checked out a open source called lean-engine but they do not have available source code for the iphone (only Android).

If possible please post source/github project!!!!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you have not already found it, the Facebook Platform Python SDK covers what you want, but not exactly written for iPhone.

If your app can get an **access_token** then you would send it to the "oauth" example of the Facebook Platform Python SDK - to the **facebookoauth.py** file. You will need to alter the "class LoginHandler" code at least, by default, it is designed to get an **access_token** out of a cookie. You would just comment out all the cookie-related code and use the **access_token** from there which can be seen in the **facebookoauth.py** code.

https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk/